# Unable to perform asynchronous action/command

Tags: php, symfony

I have a symfony app in which I need to send an email asynchronously. When my users perform certain action I need to send an email to the admin. For that I've created a symfony custom command to use with Symfony Process Component, which is similar to php native's exec(). My code is as follows:

```
    if ($trigger == true) {
        $command = 'php bin/console async-email';
        $process = new Process([$command]);
        $process->start();
        $pid = $process->getPid();
    }
```

According to the official documentation this should be enough, but I can confirm the email isn't being sent. However when I for the threat to wait for the command to end (as in not async) and print the result the command works perfectly and the email gets sent.

```
        $process->wait(function ($type, $buffer) use ($data) {
        // do stuff
        });

        return new JsonResponse([$process->getErrorOutput(), $process->getOutput(), $pid]);
```

I've also tried:

- Created a batch file with the command inside.
- Running custom php script inside the process.

Any approach works but NOT asynchronously. What I need is for the command to perform the action on the background and not interfere with the normal code execution.

Comment: I know it is a very different approach and doesn't answer the question as to why your code doesn't work but have you ever heard of the [the Messenger component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/messenger.html) which can help you perform async actions in Symfony?

Comment: Well, I didn't want to use the messenger component so as not to overcomplicate things but I may have to adopt a queque approach since the process component looks like its not meant for this

Answer (score 1):

First, If You start some async process from main process, Youe need to wait until all async processes complete  before end main process. In other case, when main process is closed, all async child processes are killed before end their tasks. This is general rule for any app.

So if You do not want to wait for e-mails sent, add mail to queue, and finish main request. Then run `php bin/console async-email` from `corn` i.e. on every 5min. This will async.

But IMHO, if user send single e-mail after some (not every) action performed,  it's totally fine to send this email synchronously from controller action.

Answer (score 0):

You're 100% correct about symfony process component behavior @Łukasz Jakubek. You can run n async child proceses (from each other) but they're main process dependant so if you don't wait or check for completion they're killed when main execution ends.

I had not quite grasped the difference between asynchromous and background. So after the recomendation given above by Julien B. I realized that a quequing system was what I needed, so I spent the last 12 hours refactoring my code to use symfony messenger with doctrine transport and voilá, works like a charm!

Might have to look a more advance quequing  system in the future like RabbitMQ which allows dynamic asynchronous queques.

For now my problem is solved and more important I'm on the right direction, thanks a lot!